# Trying to fix "tMySQL query error: Duplicate entry" For a garrysmod server

Tags: mysql, garrys-mod

I'm new to this website, and I'm not sure if I'm supposed to ask questions about mysql things in a game server. Anyways, I'm trying to fix this error here, and I was wondering if there's anything I can do to figure out, or solve where the issue is occurring.

```
    Trace:
        1: Line 32      "Trace" lua/includes/extensions/debug.lua
        2: Line 33      "nil"   gamemodes/catalystrp/gamemode/data.lua
3       C function
        4: Line 84      "nil"   lua/includes/modules/hook.lua


tMySQL query error: Duplicate entry 'STEAM_0:0:53698800' for key 'PRIMARY'Query:
 INSERT INTO metrorp_wallets (`steam`, `rpname`) VALUES('STEAM_0:0:53698800', 'T
```

Answer (score 0):

what this error means is that you are trying to insert a row to the table that conflicts with row already in the table (meaning- there's already a row in the table with the same primary key).

How to deal with this case is really a matter of what you are trying to do. I can think of three ways to go here:

1. if this case is illegal, than I guess you should not change the query, but handle the error (exception, log, whatever)
2. if you want to replace the data in the table with the new row, use `REPLACE INTO` instead of `INSERT INTO` in your query.
3. if you want to keep the data that's already there, use `INSERT IGNORE` in your query.